# Portrait Orientation is losing touch input

Tags: iphone, touch, orientation, portrait

I'm making a universal apps with auto rotation, and I'm only using landscape left and right.  When I rotate the iPhone to the portrait down position, I can see what looks like a window underneath the app rotating and I no longer get touch events.

In all the shouldAutoRotate functions I'm making sure only return true for landscape, and the info.plist only allows landscape left and right.

Comment: Check if the frames/bounds of your windows/views are also being rotated properly. It can be the case that when rotating the drawing is happening outside the bounds and then no touches will be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your view is not correctly resizing after an orientation change. Easy way to check this is to set the background color to something non-white.

Comment: I changed the background colours for the UIWindow and UIView to white and grey (backgrounds were black).  Now when I rotate the iphone, a black window rotates around the app, and I have no idea what that could be.